# Proyecto de Android no compila despues de clonar en git

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

> Tengo un problema al clonar un proyecto de git, cuando abre en el IDE Android Studio, y le doy en "Play" se queda cargando y no pasa de ahi nunca

En la pestaña de build, se queda cargando y muestra este mensaje

> Configure projects...
>
> Quiero mencionar, que ya realice muchas opciones para tratar de solucionarlo y no resulta nada
>
> La versión de Android Studio que tengo es
> **Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3**
>
> Igual les dejo los pasos que ya intente

1. **Ya invalidé caches/restart** y millón de veces y nada :(
2. **Ya borré la carpeta .idea, .gradle de la raíz del proyecto**

3.**Ya desintale e instale nuevamente el IDE Android Studio**

2. **Ya reinicié mi computadora** mil veces y tampoco
3. **Ya he clonado muchas veces el proyecto y no funciona**
4. **Ya lo movi de directorio a otras carpetas y tampoco**
5. **YA desactive el Firewall de windows, el proxy tambien y el modo offline** y nada

[image: asi se queda mi IDE y de ahi no pasa]

> Espero me puedan dar alguna otra idea de como solucionarlo, estoy desesperado, mi trabajo depende de esto, gracias

Comment: Que error se muestra al indicar que no puede construir tu proyecto?

Comment: Error: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again

Comment: ¿Ya probaste yendo a `Tools -> Clean Project y luego Tools -> Rebuild Project`?

Comment: Si ya lo intenté varias veces, pero no pasa del Gradle build running.. y ahora me muestra este mensaje: Your anti-virus program might be impacting your build performance. Android Studio checked the following directories: 
     C:\Users\Qualtop\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3
     C:\Users\Qualtop\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
     C:\Users\Qualtop\StudioProjects\MVL_ANDROID_AJM
     C:\Users\Qualtop\.gradle